# Is there a way to shorten Require.js's require statement? Am I misunderstanding how to use it?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've started using require.js for my website, but one thing that bugs me is this massive require statement at the top of my files.

```
require(["hype", "jquery", "knockout", "environment","bootstrap", "datamodel", "datatable", "datatables", "dataTablesBootstrap", "utils", "notifications", "moment", "datatablesFilterDelay"],
function(hype, $, ko, env, bootstrap, datamodel, datatable, datatables, dataTablesBootstrap, utils, not, moment, dfd) {
```

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how I'm supposed to use require.js. Each of my pages have their respective javascript files with a require statement like this at the top.

I could probably shorten it by refactoring everything that I'm including into a single module and just require that since many pages rely on similar things (most need hype, jquery, knockout, bootstrap, etc), but I'm not sure if it's the best practice thing to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this "massive" require statement bothersome?

Comment: It's not largely bothersome, just in the way that I have this same long line in multiple files, and changes to the plugins I'm requiring require changes to all of them. I just have this feeling that I'm missing something that could shorten this or clean it up, like putting this inside a config file or something.

Comment: grouping everything you need all the time together in a single "holder" module that you can then require in one fell sweep does seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Having lots of dependencies is against Single Responsibility Principle of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) Principles.

> The more dependencies our class takes in, the higher its efferent coupling to other classes, meaning that it knows a little bit too much. If it knows too much, it is  most likely because it is also doing too much. The class is no longer focused on one thing.

[This link](http://hadihariri.com/2012/04/09/dealing-wht-the-too-many-dependencies-problem/) is about dealing too many dependencies problem when Injection and C# is used, but I believe it is right for any language.

Although, if you do not want to to re-factor you code, there is a risk of mismatched dependency names with named function arguments, and it can start to look a bit strange if your module has many dependencies. http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar contains some suggestion how to make your code easier.